# pip stuck while "Using cached wheezy.template-0.1.167.tar.gz"

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I recently had issues with my local Anaconda version and decided to reinstall it.

I chose the newest version (Anaconda 5.0.1 (Python 3.6)) and started to reinstall all my packages.

There's a **problem installing pyimzml package**.

To install it, I've tried:

```
pip install pyimzml
```

and

```
pip install git+git://github.com/alexandrovteam/pyimzML.git
```

Pip always gets stuck during `Using cached wheezy.template-0.1.167.tar.gz`.

Tried to install wheezy.template as source tarball from PyPI with pip, then it stucks at `Processing c:\users\kawu\downloads\wheezy.template-0.1.167.tar.gz`.

**What can I do?**

Comment: Have you done `pip install pymzML` ?

Comment: `pip install pyimzml` (its another package than pymzML)

Comment: try `pip install git+git://github.com/alexandrovteam/pyimzML.git`

Comment: Same problem, it still stucks at `Using cached wheezy.template-0.1.167.tar.gz`

Comment: have you installed the dependency: lxml ? If lxml is not installed, pyimzML will instead use the built-in cElementTree or ElementTree package. Are you following the requisites?

Comment: lxml is installed, but wheezy.template is not. But I am not able to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following steps (Windows 10 x64 machine):

1. Download wheezy.template tarball
2. Extract it and remove the `nthreads=2` within the setup.py code.
3. Install wheezy.template with the `python .\setup.py install` command.
4. Install pyimzml

I tried many ways to install wheezy.template in my machine, like pip by network, pip/easy_install from local file, but the way above was the only way working out. I can not explain why but it works.

Comment: i'm happy you fixed it!